# Undo effects of adb screenrecord

Tags: adb

I tried out the screenrecord command through adb and executed it while my device was still locked (not sure if thats what caused it).

Now my lockscreen is in landscape mode with black bars around the side, and I can't use my touchscreen. I tried rebooting, but the problem persists. I currently can't use my device because of this, does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I finally manage to fix it using `adb shell wm size reset`